# Facebook friends list for JSONArray to JSONObjects

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm using facebook graph api to get the current user friend list.

 i have the right permissions to do it, and the returned JSON object return something like that:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "name": "name1", 
  "id": "11111"
}, 
{
  "name": "name2", 
  "id": "2222"
}, 
{
  "name": "name3", 
  "id": "33333"
}], 
"paging": {
"next": "https://graph.facebook.com/613714903/friends?format=json&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=100003711723705"
}
}
```

to my understanding this is an JSONArray and each user name and id are a JSONObjects..
i wrote this code to encode it:

```
FacebookFriend[] facebookFriends = null;        
    try {

            facebookResults = facebookResults.getJSONArray(0);
            facebookFriends = new FacebookFriend[facebookResults.length()];
            for (int i=0; i < facebookResults.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(facebookResults.getJSONObject(i).toString());
                facebookFriends[i].setuId(json.getString("id"));
                facebookFriends[i].setProfilePicture(getProfilePicture(json.getString("id")));
                facebookFriends[i].setGender(getGender(json.getString("id")));
            }               

        } catch (JSONException e) { 
            Log.e("Facebook Error", e.toString());          
            alert("Facebook Error", e.toString(),"ok");
        }
```

i get the following error:

```
 org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

i can't really understand why...

Comment: at which line you got this exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely maybe you missed that users array placed in **data** property of result *object*

Comment: isn't that the facebookResults.getJSONArray(0); ?

Comment: facebookResults.getJSONArray("data");